# Have UIScrollView Animation Pause and Restart on Gesture Touch

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view that is holding a scrollview and a uiwebview with html inside of it. I am trying to have the scrollview slowly autoatically scroll down to the bottom, pause when touched and then restart the animation at the current position.

As of right now I have the html showing, the scrollview scrolling and the touch stopping the scroll but I am not able to get the scroll animation to start up again at the current position after a certain amount of time after the touch. Here is the code:

```
      - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *myHTML = @"<html><body><h1>Hello, world!</h1><h1>Hello, world!</h1><h1>Hello, world!</h1><h1>Hello, world!</h1><h1>Hello, world!</h1><h1>Hello, world!</h1><h1>Hello, world!</h1><h1>Hello, world!</h1><h1>Hello, world!</h1><h1>Hello, world!</h1><h1>Hello, world!</h1><h1>Hello, world!</h1><h1>Hello, world!</h1><h1>Hello, world!</h1></body></html>";

    [self.webView loadHTMLString:myHTML baseURL:nil];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(userDidTapWebView)];
    [self.webView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    recognizer.delegate = self;
    [recognizer release];

    //Start the scrolling
    [self startAnimation];

}

#pragma mark - Gesture Delegate

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
       shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    //Stop the scrollview from scrolling when the screen is touched
    [self.scrollView.layer removeAllAnimations];

    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - Animate Methods

-(void)startAnimation{
    [UIScrollView beginAnimations:@"scrollAnimation" context:nil];
    [UIScrollView setAnimationDuration:8.0f];
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0 , 100)];
    [UIScrollView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)dealloc{
    [super dealloc];
    [self.webView release];
    [self.scrollView release];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the code to start the animation again: [how to call a method of multiple arguments with delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634790/how-to-call-a-method-with-delay)

And also when you call the removeAllAnimations, the scroll view will jump to the final position it is intended, so it is not really paused like what you want.

You can take a look at how to pause and resume the animation here: [Is there a way to pause a CABasicAnimation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306870/is-there-a-way-to-pause-a-cabasicanimation)

So, putting them all together (with additional checking to resume again the animation if the scroll view is touched again):

```
-(void)pauseLayer:(CALayer*)layer
{
    CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
    layer.speed = 0.0;
    layer.timeOffset = pausedTime;
}

-(void)resumeLayer:(CALayer*)layer
{
    CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer timeOffset];
    layer.speed = 1.0;
    layer.timeOffset = 0.0;
    layer.beginTime = 0.0;
    CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - pausedTime;
    layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
       shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    if (self.scrollView.layer.timeOffset>0) {
        [self resumeLayer:self.scrollView.layer]; //resume the animation on the subsequent touch
    }
    else {
        //first we pause the animation
        [self pauseLayer:self.scrollView.layer];

        //after certain seconds we will start again the animation
        double delayInSeconds = 2.0; //adjust this value
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [self resumeLayer:self.scrollView.layer];
        });
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I implemented the code and the delegate methods still did not pick up.