# How do we wait for a while before detecting next action?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Basically this is what I like to do:

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
     uint32_t collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);
     if (collision == (CNPhysicsCategoryCat|CNPhysicsCategoryBed)) {
         _catNode.userData = [@{@"catOnBed":@(YES)} mutableCopy];
         //Code here can let me wait for 3 seconds or something.
         (_catNode.userData[@"catOnBed"])?[self win]:[self lose];
     }
     if (collision == (CNPhysicsCategoryCat|CNPhysicsCategoryEdge)) {
         [self lose];
     }
}
```

So I want the detection be done 3 seconds after the contact happens.

I tried dispatch_time method and it returns "breakpoint 2.1" to me. Screenshots below:

[image: Breakpoint 2.1]
[image: Breakpoint 2.1]

Then I also tried performSelector method and it tells me undeclared "detectContact..."

[image: detectContact]

I also created the method, here is the evidence.

[image: evidence]

And then I tried SKAction sequence method (I think this one is closed). And it failed too:

[image: SKAction sequence]

And here is the stack trace:

[image: Stack Trace]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I delay a method call for 1 second?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920675/how-can-i-delay-a-method-call-for-1-second)

Comment: After reading it I don't think it's the same question because I am calling a method here and that question is about creating a delay through the original method.

Comment: I get the feeling that you're not even sure on what you're asking. Besides the breakpoint images you're posting are essentially useless  without the proper error returned and the stack trace.

Comment: Here is the stack trace: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9B9Tt.png

Comment: Ok, getting closer. The one on the left is the stack trace, the one on the right is plain assembly, which is useless unless you're a magician. Go to the console on the bottom, and paste the console output, the specific error should be there.

Comment: The error just says, "(lldb)." What does this mean and why does it exist?

Comment: That's the lldb command prompt, what else is there above it? Also a breakpoint is not an error: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/Creating,Disabling,andDeletingBreakpoints/Creating,Disabling,andDeletingBreakpoints.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:afterDelay]`. For more information look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsobject_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector%3awithObject%3aafterDelay%3a). Basically your code would look like this:

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
    // Other code
    [self performSelector:@selector(detectContact) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
}

- (void)detectContact {
    // Code to be execute after 3 second delay
}
```

The method detectContact would be called after 3 seconds.

Comment: It says undeclared identifier. Screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zbYWm.png

Comment: You will have to define the "detectContact" method. That was just an example method name. That method will hold whatever code you want to execute after the delay.

Comment: Where do I define this method and how do I define it while calling out the original method shown above?

Comment: You declare and implement it like any other method. I added an example to my answer.

Comment: Thanks man. It still shows the same information: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4VuMA.png

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to include "selector" as I didn't write and compile this in an editor first. Simply change `@(detectContact)` to `@selector(detectContact)`. (I also updated my answer).

Answer (score 2):

You'd could use a delayed task!

```
int64_t delay = 3;
dispatch_time_t time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delay * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    // do whatever you want to do after 3 seconds.
});
```

Comment: It gives me breakpoint 2.1 when I use this method: http://i.stack.imgur.com/e1477.png (screenshot)

Answer (score 1):

Use dispatch_time_t like so...

```
double delaySeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delaySeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    (_catNode.userData[@"catOnBed"])?[self win]:[self lose];
});
```

Comment: It gives me breakpoint 2.1 when I use this method: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Aymdp.png (screenshot)

Comment: So you have a breakpoint set, delete it. It's the blue tag on the left.

Comment: What do you mean when you said "blue tag on the left"?

Comment: Read up on breakpoints https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/Creating,Disabling,andDeletingBreakpoints/Creating,Disabling,andDeletingBreakpoints.html

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a new `SKAction` with a delay.

```
SKAction *delayedBlock = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction waitForDuration:2.0], 
                                              [SKAction runBlock:
^{
    // Perform action here.
}]]];
```

Then run it on whichever node is relevant, possibly being the `SKScene`

```
// Assuming that self is the SKScene
[self runAction:delayedBlock];
```

I would suggest using `SKAction`s over the other suggested alternatives, to be confined within the run loop of `SpriteKit`.

Comment: I think this one is the solution (or at least very closed). I still run into break point 1.1 tho: http://i.stack.imgur.com/b3kby.png

Comment: [A breakpoint isn't an error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016890/thread-1-stopped-at-breakpoint-error-when-initializing-an-nsurl-object/10016939#10016939), @AeroWindwalker.

Comment: For some reason it appears to run the desired action twice instead of just once if this method is used.

Comment: Probably because collisions occur multiple times? Make sure you only fire once.

Comment: It's odd because other methods will not result at this phenomenon.