# How to call a method after few seconds without affecting ui?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using tableview and I want to call a method after some time duration.This method return a array and reload the tableview.I want within this time duration UI doesn't stuck.

Comment: `–performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`, perhaps?

Comment: `dispatch_after`? `NSTimer`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I delay a method call for 1 second?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920675/how-can-i-delay-a-method-call-for-1-second)

Answer (score 0):

Best to use [Grand Central Dispatch (GCD)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/performance/reference/gcd_libdispatch_ref/Reference/reference.html).  If you call `dispatch_after()`, you can run a block of code whenever you want.

```
// Run this code after 1 second.
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self someMethod];
});
```