# iOS Looking to delay segue between view controllers when button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am fairly new to swift and Objective C, and I have an app that goes from the main view controller to the second view controller on a button press. THe second view controller opens up a camera and every time I click the button there is somewhat of a lag in the camera opening. I reckon this has something to do with the thread and how the process is being handled.

I want to introduce a delay between when my button on the first view controller is placed and when the second viewcontroller is displayed on the screen. Is there a delay that can be applied this way?

Here is the code to my main view controller with the button:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func itemAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self )
    }

    @IBAction func logosAction(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue2", sender: self )
    }

    @IBOutlet var itemsButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet var carsButton: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        itemsButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        itemsButton.clipsToBounds = true

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think you should probably be looking at fixing the delay. Can you show us how you are adding the camera layer ? I have added that in viewDidAppear and works fine

Comment: I am using the first screen to connect to this open source code here. The camera initialization takes place in this viewcontroller here: 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/ios/camera/CameraExampleViewController.mm

Comment: Refer this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whenever you user `performSegue`  method then you need to use like that

> In the example with a 10 second delay

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10.0, execute: {
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self )
})
```

**Updated**

> In this example with 5 second delay

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:.now() + 5.0, execute: {
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"segue",sender: self)
})
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer, unfortunately adding this into my code does not cause the 10 second delay at all, I must be doing something incorrectly. I have the code as follows and expect a 10 second delay after I press the items button.

@IBAction func itemAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:.now() + 5.0, execute: {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"segue",sender: self)
        })
        
    }

Am i missing something here?

Comment: I do not think that you was missing something in that. i might be happened because of `cleaning code` or `project`. But at all if it's working fine you then please up vote my answer so that some one can take help of this.  I also added your code in that check updated 
Thanks

Comment: @Viv You would have probably set the segue in storyboard for the button then. Add a manual segue from view controller for this delay to work

Comment: @GoodSp33d YES! That was it!

Comment: @APKAPPS Thank you for your answer! Definitely put me on the right track :)

Answer (score 1):

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10.0) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self )
}
```

OR

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 10.0, repeats: false) { (timer) in
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self )
}
```

Comment: thank you!  I tried implementing this as follows and there was no delay after the button press at all. I'm definitely doing something incorrectly, not sure what though:
@IBAction func itemAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        
        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 10.0, repeats: false) { (timer) in
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self )
        }        
    }

Comment: @Viv below link may be useful to you https://stackoverflow.com/a/39845573